# Django: The data which I'm sending to my server doesn't get saved. Server gives 500 response

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have made a Django project and app. I want to send data to this server.
I made a script to generate random data and send it to server using post requests.

The data gets received by the server (I'm able to print it) but it doesn't save the data to the database and returns a 500 response.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import date
# Create your models here.

class Data(models.Model):

    shipment_id = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    destination = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    vehicle_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    service_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    booking_date = models.DateField(default=date.today)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Data, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.shipment_id
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from analyser.models import Data
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.http import JsonResponse
import requests


@csrf_exempt
def respond(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        resp = request.POST
        data = Data (
            shipment_id = resp.get("ID"),
            source = resp.get("src"),
            destination = resp.get("dstn"),
            vehicle_type = resp.get("vehicle_type"),
            service_type = resp.get("service_type"),
            booking_date = resp.get("date"),
        )
        data.save()
    else:
        print "GET"

    return HttpResponse("Hello")
```

Script for random data:

```
import string
import random
import requests
import json
class Data_items(object):
    def __init__(self,col1,col2,col3,col4,col5):
        self.ID = col1
        self.src = col2
        self.dstn = col3
        self.vehicle_type = col4
        self.service_type = col5


def id_generator(size=6, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):

    return "SHIPPR_"+''.join(random.SystemRandom().choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(size))

def get_random():

    vehicle_type = ["Mini","Large"]
    col1 = id_generator()
    col2 = str(random.uniform(12,18)) +","+ str(random.uniform(74,78))
    col3 = str(random.uniform(12,18)) +","+ str(random.uniform(74,78))
    col4 = random.choice(vehicle_type)
    col5 = "shipping"


    Details = Data_items(col1,col2,col3,col4,col5)
    return Details

def populate_data(n):

    for i in range(n):
        Obj = (get_random().__dict__)
        # Obj = json.dumps(Obj)
        # print Obj
        url = 'http://192.168.1.118:8000'

        resp = requests.post(url, (Obj))

populate_data(10)
```

I host the server using:

```
./manage.py runserver 0:8000
```

PS - My friend is able to send me data and the server saves it using the same exact script when I host a wifi hotspot.

What can be the problem?

Comment: What does the error log say?

Comment: have you set up the DB (and user) properly and run `python manage.py migrate`?

Comment: Yes as I said, my friend when he runs the script on his laptop connected to my hotspot, it works perfectly.

Comment: @Stefan I can see 500 response on console.

Comment: @abhyuditjain If you see a 500 response, this is mostly logged as well in the error log.. including a more specific error message. From there you can debug

Comment: @Stefan where is it? I will update the question with the log

Comment: @abhyuditjain that location is specified in your configuration..

Comment: @Stefan where is that file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  data.save()
try Data.objects.create(**kwargs)

Comment: Doesn't work. How's it different? data.save() works from the other laptop.

Comment: Yeah your method is absolutely correct. save() method checks for id first if present then it updates otherwise creates an object. Still some times object.create works

Comment: Everything is there. Everything prints to the console. It just doesn't save.